# How can I slow down execution of JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, youtube

I'm writing a script to delete all of my YouTube comments. Each line of this code works to delete one comment, but when I put it into a loop, I get an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined` that doesn't come up when I run each line individually. I'm thinking if I can figure out a way to sleep in between the lines of code I could remove the error.

```
var myList = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-trigger style-scope ytd-menu-renderer");
for(i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
    myList[i].click();
    document.getElementsByClassName("style-scope ytd-menu-navigation-item-renderer")[4].click(); //error here
    document.getElementById("confirm-button").click();
}
```

I tried using setTimeout, like this:

```
var myList = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-trigger style-scope ytd-menu-renderer");
for(i=0; i<myList.length; i++) {
    myList[i].click();
    setTimeout(function(){document.getElementsByClassName("style-scope ytd-menu-navigation-item-renderer")[4].click();}, 1000);
    setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("confirm-button").click();}, 5000);
}
```

And it returned a number of 279, but no errors, and no comments deleted. What happened?

Comment: You'll probably need to use `setTimeout`. Have you tried that?

Comment: I just reformatted to try that, and it gave me a number back of 279, but no error and no comments were deleted.

Comment: Do you know how to use setTimeout? Show your attempt in the question.

Comment: which one of the three `click` does the error refer to

Comment: There's no error returned when I use setTimeout, only when i run the first snippet. I noted where the error occurs in a code comment, it's the second click.

Comment: @ian-campbell Indent by four spaces. See how I did it in the edit. And you'll need to either delay the second click by more than the first, or start the second click from the first click callback.

Comment: Ok will try that.

Comment: sorry about that - side scroll :p perhaps `document.getElementsByClassName("style-scope ytd-menu-navigation-item-renderer")` doesn't (always) return (at least) 5 elements - or perhaps you need to wait for `myList[i].click();` to "finish" before blindly going on to the next line

Comment: Still nothing. The dialog box of "Delete your comment and all of its replies permanently?" comes up, which is the second-to-last line of code, but the last line doesn't execute because the comment does not get deleted, even though the dialog box disappears. Is there a way to tell what is happening?

Comment: the settimeout code is doomed to fail ... all `myList[i].click();` get clicked immediately ... then after 1 second, a bunch of `getElementsByClassName("style-scope ytd-menu-navigation-item-renderer")[4]` get clicked ... then after 4 seconds `document.getElementById("confirm-button")` gets clicked a bunch of times

Comment: Again, if you call each click from the previous click callback, it might work. There's probably a function you could write to make it neater, but a triple nested callback isn't the end of the world for a small script. There's a way to make it work, you'll just have to get creative. `setTimeout` is, afaik, the only construct JS has to achieve delaying code.

Comment: How could I try calling the click from the previous click callback? Just some pseudocode so I can see what you mean.

Comment: @ian-campbell Wrap the first `myList` click in a `setTimeout`, then in the first setTimeout callback after the click, start a new setTimeout that executes the second click, then after, from the second click callback start a new setTimeout that does the third click after a delay. You could also just create a function that achieves that for you. I wrote some code for school that did that. It wasn't that difficult to whip together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all below options are a bit "hackish" - but there's no consistent and easy way to get a notification when a click event has been fully processed.
You could add your own click event listener to the targeted element, but then, that can be "muted" by stopPropagation ...
even then, there's no (easy) way to know when the DOM has finished "repainting" as a result of the click event - you could look at using 
[MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), I guess

I assume *(never do that)* that the element targeted by `document.getElementsByClassName("style-scope ytd-menu-navigation-item-renderer")[4]` is dynamically added as a result of clicking `myList[i].click();` 
which is why you have the issue. After `myList[i].click();` the DOM won't be "updated" for "some time" - so,  `document.getElementsByClassName("style-scope ytd-menu-navigation-item-renderer")` could easily fail.

> A potential issue is if deleting comments changes the number of elements targeted by `document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-trigger style-scope ytd-menu-renderer");` - as `HTMLCollection`s are "live", removing a DOM element will mutate the `HTMLCollection` - only the last two code snippets will be immune to this possibility

So, here are four different ways you can do this

---

option 1 - ES5, just plain ol' callbacks

```
var DELAY = 0; // try 0, then try increasing values
var myList = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-trigger style-scope ytd-menu-renderer");
function confirmClick(callback3) {
    document.getElementById("confirm-button").click();
    setTimeout(callback3, DELAY);
}
function itemClick(callback2, callback3)  {
    document.getElementsByClassName("style-scope ytd-menu-navigation-item-renderer")[4].click();
    setTimeout(callback2, DELAY, callback3);
}
function listClick(element, callback1, callback2, callback3) {
    element.click();
    setTimeout(callback1, DELAY, callback2, callback3);
}
function doOne(i) {
    listClick(myList[i], itemClick, confirmClick, function() {
        ++i;
        if (i < myList.length) {
            doOne(i);
        }
    });
}
doOne(0);
```

---

> As you are trying to "chain" multiple asynchronous (sort of) processes together, `Promise`'s (seem) to make the code a little less cumbersome

option 2 - Promise, but with nested `setTimeout`'s - 
uses `Array#reduce` to chain the clicks together so they process strictly one after the other

This is ugly, really ugly, *lets leave pyramid building to dead Egyptians*, 
included to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve

```
var DELAY = 0; // try 0, then try increasing values
var myList = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-trigger style-scope ytd-menu-renderer");
var p = Promise.resolve();
for(i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
    myList[i].click();
    p = p.then(() => new Promise(resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            document.getElementsByClassName("style-scope ytd-menu-navigation-item-renderer")[4].click();
            setTimeout(() => {
                document.getElementById("confirm-button").click();
                setTimeout(resolve, DELAY);
            }, DELAY);
        }, DELAY);
    });
}
```

---

option 3 - Promise with a helper function - basically the above code, but added a helper function to prevent the pyramid

```
const DELAY = 0; // try 0, then try increasing values
const clickThenDelay = element => new Promise(resolve => {
    element.click();
    setTimeout(resolve, DELAY);
});
var myList = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-trigger style-scope ytd-menu-renderer");

Array.from(myList).reduce((p, item) => { 
    return p
    .then(() => clickThenDelay(item))
    .then(() => clickThenDelay(document.getElementsByClassName("style-scope ytd-menu-navigation-item-renderer")[4]))
    .then(() => clickThenDelay(document.getElementById("confirm-button")))
}, Promise.resolve());
```

---

option 4 - similar to option 3, but this one adds a click event handler before firing click, which is removed after click has been "handled".
Presumably the last added handler is called last. Not sure if that is guaranteed, however.
Also, this will not work if an earlier handler calls `event.stop[Immediate]Propagation()`

```
const DELAY = 0; // try 0, then try increasing values
const clickThenDelay = element => new Promise(resolve => {
    const handleClick = () => {
        element.removeEventListener('click', handleClick);
        setTimeout(resolve, DELAY); // wait for repaint? Perhaps a MutationObserver event could be useful here?
    }
    element.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
    element.click();
});
var myList = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-trigger style-scope ytd-menu-renderer");

Array.from(myList).reduce((p, item) => {
    return p
    .then(clickThenDelay(item))
    .then(() => clickThenDelay(document.getElementsByClassName("style-scope ytd-menu-navigation-item-renderer")[4]))
    .then(() => clickThenDelay(document.getElementById("confirm-button")))
}, Promise.resolve());
```

Comment: Tried Option 1, got the error `callback3 is not defined`

Comment: hmm, hang on, that's not the error I thought you got :p

Comment: And that's why I hate the callback method - gotta catch em all :p - edited and hopefully fixed

Comment: Option 1 worked perfectly! Very fast too. Option 3 and 4 didn't work, just returned a `Promise {<pending>}` and stopped there.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid that 4 wasn't going to work - surprised that 3 didn't though - the fact that the result is a (pending) promise is expected though - I see how I stuffed them up now though!

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is that the page hasn't had time to update the DOM since you executed the `.click()` function.  You need to give it that time, perhaps with `requestAnimationFrame` or the less precise `setTimeout`.  In the solution below (completely untested, made up on the spot), the progression is to do each action (open the dropdown, click delete, confirm) after a pause to give the DOM time to update.  Consider:

```
function deleteAllComments ( ) {
    'use strict';
    var commentsToDelete, i;

    function openNextCommentOptionsDropdown ( ) {
        if ( ! (++i < commentsToDelete.length ) ) {
            console.log('No more comments to remove.');
            return;
        }

        commentsToDelete[i].click();
        setTimeout(activateCommentDeleteButton, 50);
    }

    function activateCommentDeleteButton ( ) {
        var el = document.getElementsByClassName("style-scope ytd-menu-navigation-item-renderer")[4];

        if ( ! el ) {
            console.warn('No "Delete" button found, at comment #', i, commentsToDelete[i]);
            console.log('Stopping delete operation');
            return;
        }

        el.click();
        setTimeout(activateCommentDeleteConfirmationButton, 50);
    }

    function activateCommentDeleteConfirmationButton ( ) {
        var el = document.getElementById("confirm-button");

        if ( ! el ) {
            console.warn('Unable to confirm comment delete action, at comment #', i, commentsToDelete[i]);
            console.log('Stopping delete operation');
            return;
        }

        el.click();
        setTimeout(openNextCommentOptionsDropdown, 50); // continue larger "loop"
    }

    commentsToDelete = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-trigger style-scope ytd-menu-renderer");

    openNextCommentOptionsDropdown(); // start the "loop"
}
```

There are two big details here:

1. Giving the DOM time to update in response to the actions the code has initiated (`setTimeout(..., 50)`, where 50ms should be more than enough time; decrease as necessary, or just use `requestAnimationFrame`.
2. Defensive coding: before blindly executing functions on returned items, first check that the items actually exist (`if ( ! el ) { ... }`)

Comment: Gave it a try, got a response of `undefined`

Comment: What did you try?  Did you just copy and paste?  It's a function, so you have to actually call it to begin the computation.

Comment: Called the function `deleteAllComments()` and it returned the "No more comments to remove." response.

Comment: Strange because when I do it isolated like `var commentsToDelete = document.getElements...` it's a fully populated HTMLCollection with a length over 200.